# How to build tensorflow from source with a model that uses custom ops which are renamed versions of existing ops?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I have a `.tflite` model that uses custom operations called `MaxPoolingWithArgmax2D`, `MaxUnpooling2D`, and `Convolution2DTransposeBias`.
These ops are actually not custom ops, since they are present in tensorflow already ([MaxPoolWithArgmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops/MaxPoolWithArgmax), [MaxUnpooling2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/layers/MaxUnpooling2D), [conv2d_transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d_transpose))

After consulting [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_custom), I see that I'd have to write a kernel and an interface for these ops.

Is there a way to build tensorflow source without writing custom implementations for these ops since they're already present in the library? The only problem is that the model I'm using has renamed them due to which they're being recognized as custom ops. My goal is to perform inference with this model.

Edit: These ops are not select ops. They are built-in ops present inside the base library. However, the person who wrote this model renamed them, which makes them custom ops.

Edit 2: Photo for reference: [image]

Comment: Please clarify what platform you are going to use to run tflite model.

Comment: I'm making a custom binary for android

Comment: I would suggest firstly try to use [selected ops package](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select#android_aar) (with model conversion method described bellow), maybe your ops already available. If this is a case you can build custom AAR with only required by model ops and reduce package size.

Comment: Like I answered below, these ops aren't select ops. They are normal ops that have simply been renamed, which makes them custom ops. FYI I had already built with select ops before but the AAR gave a custom op error during inference.

Comment: Another question: are there all ops renamed or there is a mix of normal naming/custom naming for those 3?

Comment: All occurrences of these ops are renamed. Their built-in names are not used in the model

Comment: You may try to edit tflite, for example via tflite->[onnx](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx)->[tflite](https://github.com/joshuacwnewton/ONNX-to-TFLite) conversion with onnx edit to normal naming. I have looked through tensorflow repo and cant give you an option how to make custom interpreter for your model.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the existin TF ops through the Select TF option in the TFLite.

For example, during the conversion stage, you can enable them:

```
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
  tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
  tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS # enable TensorFlow ops.
]
```

For the inference stage, please make sure that the select tf dependency is linked. When using TF Python API, it will automatically be enabled.

Please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select).

---

Among the custom ops, the custom operator implementations for some of them are being distributed as a perception operator package.

```
from tensorflow.lite.kernels.perception import pywrap_perception_ops as perception_ops_registerer
from tensorflow.lite.python import interpreter as interpreter_wrapper

interpreter = interpreter_wrapper.InterpreterWithCustomOps(
          model_content=model,
          custom_op_registerers=[
            perception_ops_registerer.PerceptionOpsRegisterer
          ])
```

Please take a look at this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/kernels/perception/perception_ops.cc#L22).

Comment: Your reply refers to select ops, not custom ops. They are different.

Comment: Select TF ops are used to avoid using custom ops and use the existing TensorFlow ops so you can avoid the custom op implementation requirements.

Comment: what is the version of TensorFlow required to execute the second chunk of code? i tried tf-nightly but I got the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.lite.kernels'

Comment: The above code will be available from the bazel development.